# ASP Web Api suddenly returns no data

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have recently developed an Xamarin Forms App and a Web API in .NET core.

The app is published in Google Play and App Store and everything works perfect but my web api sometimes returns no data for no reason.

I have been testing for a while now with the web api on my IIS server and never had this problem before.

**This is the response I get:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var currentLocation = window.location.href;
        if(currentLocation.indexOf('?') == -1){
            currentLocation += '?';
        } else {
            currentLocation += '&';
        }
        window.location = currentLocation+'redirectedByJavascript=true';
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Every single request I made returned the same response. Even requests that would be a 404 where returning 200 with the above snippet.

I have no idea why this happened. While trying to find a solution it also fixed itself. Suddenly I started getting back data from the web api. The problem is this is not the first time and won't be the last time either.

Comment: "I have been testing for a while now with the web api on my IIS server and never had this problem before." Where is your web API when this problem happens? Your works are ambiguous.

Comment: @LexLi How do you mean "where is it?" I have a VPS where it runs on.

Comment: A VPS not only provides you a raw Windows Server, but also a full stack of its networking. So when such issues happen when you host the app on VPS, your only option is to capture packets on that server and hope from them you can get some hints on who sends those empty responses. In many cases, IIS might not 
be the culprit.

Comment: @LexLi Can I use Wireshark for this? Or do you have any other suggestions?